# Read CSV File and display values when there are empty rows in between using java

Tags: java, csv

I am able the read the csv file but when the row is blank or empty it is showing Arrayindexoutofboundexception. how to continue the reading a file when the row is empty also.

```
File file = new File("D:\\ms.csv");
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        for (String line : lines) {
            String[] array = line.split(",");
            System.out.println(array[0]+","+array[1]);
        }
```

My csv looks like below in between there are empty rows

```
sid,    name,   image

PC-GHF - 10677, Wine,   /g/h/ghf_10677.jpg






PC-GHF - 10482, Green,  /g/h/ghf_10482.jpg




PC-GHF - 10483, Shaded Cream,   /g/h/ghf_10483..jpg




PC-GHF- 10484,  White,  /g/h/ghf_10484.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the length before display it.

```
 for (String line : lines) {
        String[] array = line.split(",");
        if (array.length == 0) 
            continue;
        System.out.println(array[0]+","+array[1]);
    }
```

OR

```
   for (String line : lines) {
        if (line.lenght == 0) 
            continue;
        String[] array = line.split(",");
        System.out.println(array[0]+","+array[1]);
    }
```

Comment: and if there is an empty field in column3 it is giving exception

Comment: then change the checking to  `array.length < 3`

Answer (score 0):

You can skip a specific line using the [`continue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) statement:

```
for (String line : lines) {
    if ("".equals(line)) {
        continue;
    }
    // ...
}
```

(You might have to adapt the if condition, if your empty lines are containing  blanks)